# Negation of $x∈A\cup B$ without using $\cup$

Tags: logic, elementary-set-theory

Construct the negation of each statement below without using the following symbols: ∩, ∪, ⊆, ⊇, ⊂, ⊃, \, △, and =.

I know that the negation is simply $x∉A\cup B$, but how do I represent that without using the ∉ symbol? Thanks!

Could I say x ∈ ~A $\land$ ~B ?

Can I even use the and symbol $\land$ on sets?

Comment: Did you mean "without using the $\cup$ symbol"?

Comment: Yes, I can't use the U symbol to negate it.

Comment: I'm not sure what your last comment means.  The $\notin$ symbol is not on your list in the first paragraph of things you can't use.

Comment: Does $\wedge$ mean "and"?  If so, you can't use it on sets, but you can use it on sentences, and that might give a clue as to how to solve the problem

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I can't use the union symbol ∪. I CAN use the ∉ symbol. So I can't negate it by saying x∉A∪B because that uses the ∪ symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $x \in A \cap B$ if and only if $x \in A$ and $x \in B$.  You can say a similar thing for $\cup$ and "or".

Comment: You're welcome.  Don't forget to accept the best answer by clicking the check mark next to it on the left (feel free to wait for more answers if you like.)